# TypeError: not enough arguments for format string in print()

Tags: python, typeerror

I am trying to code a program to write a file:

```py
print("Team %s, %s\t\t\t\tWon %s\t\t\tLost %s\t\t\tPercentage $%.3f"%(team,won,lost,perc))
```

but when I run it it keeps saying:

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: This string was expecting five different variables to be passed, but you only passed four

Comment: You have five `%` placeholders in your string, and you're only specifying four values to go into them.

Comment: If you're using python >=3.6, you may want to look into using f-strings

Answer (score 2):

You have given it five variables to format, or five places you used `%` in your string, but you only pass it four variables to populate it with `(team,won,lost,perc)`. You either need to remove a `%s` from your string or pass it another variable.

```
print("Team %s, %s\t\t\t\tWon %s\t\t\tLost, %s\t\t\tPercentage $%.3f"%(team,won,lost,lost,perc))
```

This may have been what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

```
print("Team %s, %s\t\t\t\tWon %s\t\t\tLost %s\t\t\tPercentage $%.3f"%(team,won,lost,perc))
```

Here You are using 5 times `%` format specifier in print function and You're providing only 4 argument(team,won,lost,perc)  that's why

`TypeError: not enough arguments for format string`

Either you have to provide 5 arguments

```
print("Team %s, %s\t\t\t\tWon %s\t\t\tLost %s\t\t\tPercentage $%.3f"%(team,won,argument,lost,perc))
```

Or you may have putted 2nd `%s` mistakenly . So the correct format can be

```
print("Team %s, \t\t\t\tWon %s\t\t\tLost %s\t\t\tPercentage $%.3f"%(team,won,argument,lost,perc))
```

Hope it would help You :-)